# Copy a file using makefile

Tags: gnu-make

I created the following makefile to generate a.pdf and then copy it to b.pdf.

```
all:
    arara a.tex
    rm *.dvi *.aux *.log
    cp a.pdf b.pdf
```

The first two commands run correctly: meaning a file named a.pdf is generated, and the temporary *.dvi, *.aux, *.log files are removed.

But the cp command does not run: meaning b.pdf is not created. Any idea why? I tried cp -f as well.

(arara is a utility to compile a tex file and generate a pdf file, its details are not important for this question)

Comment: What do you mean "does not run"?  Does make print the command?  Does the command show an error?  Please show the command you typed and the output you got.  There's no way that this command won't run given the makefile you show here.

Comment: clarified the question.

Comment: You still didn't say: did make show the `cp` command?  Did you get any errors or other messages?  You can try adding `-v` to the `cp` command to get verbose output.  If you run that command from your shell prompt, does it work?

Comment: I found the issue and added it as an answer. The steps you outlined helped me debug the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error turned out to be in the rm command and not in the cp command. One of the extensions *.aux did not exist and so rm threw an error. I resolved it by adding -f to the rm command.